# What is the Big-O of this section of code?

Tags: big-o

```
x = 0;
for (i = 1; i <= n; i = i * 3) // Is big(O) of this statement O(log base 3 n)?
{ 
    if (i % 2 != 0) 
        for (j = 0; j < i; j++) // What will be big(O) of this loop and how?
            x++; 
}
```

I read an answer that overall big-O will be O(n). How will be big(O) of this code O(n) if this is true?

Answer (score 2):

The inner loop will execute i operations for each i from 0 to log_3(n). So the number of operations performed is given by [this common sum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/1_%2B_2_%2B_3_%2B_4_%2B_%E2%8B%AF#Partial_sums). It has a closed form of (log_3(n) + 1)(log_3(n))/2 which is O([log n]^2)

Comment: O(n^2) is for inner loop?

Comment: O(n^2) is the whole thing.

Comment: Ok. The summation you did,this was for inner loop?

Comment: Ugh. I don't know what I was thinking here.. i is tripling each time, not adding. This answer is incorrect.